# Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() Returns HTML contents

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, wif, adfs, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing an application (mobile app later) to call web api functions. The web api site is linked to ADFS authentication.

My current difficulty is that ReadAsStringAsync() doesn't return a correct value. Instead it returns a long HTML content looking like a login page or error page.

What am I doing wrong?

ADFS details: (they are all valid)
  Type: WS-trust/SAML/WS-Federation
  Certificate: 
    service communication CN=*.xxx.org Issued to: *.xxx.org Issued by: **** - G2
    Token-decrypting: Issued to ADFF Encryption - adfs.xxx.com
         Issued by: ADFS Encryption - adfs.xxx.com

```
Token-signing: 
      Issued to: ADFS signing -adfs.xxx.com
      Issued by: ADF Signing - adfs.xxx.com
Relaying Party Trusts:
      Identifiers: https://api.xxx.com
                    https://api.xxx.com/api
End Points: 
      WS-Federation Passive Endpoints
                    https://api.xxx.com
      SAML-Assertion Consumer Endpoints
                    https://api.xxx.com

Secure hash algorithm: sha-1
Claim Rules
  Issuance Transform Rules: (Send LDAP attt as claims) email -> email, given->given, surname->surname,UPN->UPN
                            (Transform an incoming Claim) Email -> Name ID in email format.
  Issuance Authorization Rules: Permit access to All users. Permit for issued claims.
```

The below test codes were created with information from internet but I cannot remember where they came from because I tried so many examples.

Returned HTML contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10.000"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,no-store"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
        <meta name='mswebdialog-title' content='Connecting to *** College'/>

        <title>Sign In</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function LoginErrors(){this.userNameFormatError = 'Enter your user ID in the format \u0026quot;domain\\user\u0026quot; or \u0026quot;user@domain\u0026quot;.'; this.passwordEmpty = 'Enter your password.';}
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA["
.........................
.........................
</script>
</head>
.........................
.........................
</html>
```

My code:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var samlToken = GetIdentityToken();

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", samlToken.ToString());



            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
              HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Values");


            //request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.SendAsync(request);            

            response2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var result2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
            textBox1.Text = result2; // This results are long and in HTML.

        }
    private string GetIdentityToken()
        {
            string endpointUri = string.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed", _serverName);

            var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                          new UserNameWSTrustBinding(),
                          new EndpointAddress(endpointUri));

            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
            if (factory.Credentials != null)
            {
                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = _password;
            }

            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(_relyingPartyUri),
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
            };

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
                var token2 = token as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
                return token2.TokenXml.OuterXml;
            }
            catch (ProtocolException ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

    public class UserNameWSTrustBinding : WS2007HttpBinding
    {
        public UserNameWSTrustBinding()
        {
            Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
            Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're getting that because that is what the server returns. Seems like it thinks you're not authenticated so it sends you to a login page.

Comment: Evan, you seem to be right. However I got a generic XML token and every step of httpclient requests returns 200 or OK. However the last request (await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync) seems to be wrong. /api/values will return only one string value. any magic solution?